# What is the difference between "test" and "runSplit" options in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J017n.png)

Is there a difference between "test" and "runSplit" options in IntelliJ IDEA? When I click on the green arrow next to the test class in java, it always gives me these two options for the first time.